# regex to extract last integer values

Tags: java, regex

I have to extract end integer part from string  in java

use **regx** in java

like:-

```
String s1="allow23"// extract 23
String s2="4code68"//  extract 68
```

only integers from end (after alphabet or no alphabet)

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) is a great resource for learning regex.

Comment: @ java Mentor I am trying to find a regex which can work . .If you can't help why Interfere in between .

Comment: @user2263148 If you’re a developer and you’re about to ask another developer a technical question (on a forum, via email, on a chat channel, or in person), you’d better be ready to answer the question “What have you tried?”. More info at http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: Asking a helpful question more easily yields a helpful answer. By providing what you've tried, it may be simple to locate a minor error rather than redeveloping an entire solution for you. Plus, many people will be unwilling to help if you don't show that you've made an effort to try.

Comment: thanks . .friends for help . downvote or upvote.I don't care. if question is bad sure down vote . and sorry not to post what tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex can be `(\\d+$)`. The full code example is:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    int number = Integer.pareseInt(m.group(1));
}
```

I hope this can be a good start for you to learn regular expressions in java.

Comment: Why capturing group? Just access the match from group 0.